# meaning of 'run' in '...how a project choked by a tight budget gets run.'

Tags: word-meaning

This is a sentence from a [*The Atlantic* article](https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2022/02/gun-safety-hollywood-alec-baldwin/622836/).

> Hollywood has a long history of notoriously harsh labor practices, and
> the *Run* incident—which happened as members of the International
> Alliance of Theatrical Stage Employees were preparing to potentially
> strike—raises questions about how a project choked by a tight budget
> gets **run**.

Is the meaning of **run** in bold 'a series of performances of a play or film'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking of *run* as a noun, but here it is the passive participle, meaning ‘managed’.

Comment: Thank you very much.